# JAVA EE Accessibility

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was going through the fundamentals of JAVA EE 6, [Introducing the Java EE 6 Platform: Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/javaee6overview-141808.html) and came to know that Accessibility is one of its prominent distinguishing feature from the JAVA SE. Please help with me to know what exactly this feature is and how it differs from [SE Accessibility](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/access/). I am new to the Java EE, so please forgive me if there is any mistake and feel free to comment about it..

Comment: Hi Arun. Welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry but a question like this is not specific enough. You could quote the article you read, the and ask the specific question you have. 

Maybe you were looking to see how web applications are easily distributable compared to desktop applications ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application might help

Comment: Sorry ..I posted this because i was not able to have any search links commenting about this. I will change the question by adding the article..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessibility in the first article you posted means that a Java EE application can provide interfaces to be accessed in various ways (e.g. Webservices, HTML-Websites...).

Accessibility in the second article means support for disabled people (e.g. better contrast or larger UI elements).

The two terms do not have anything in common in these two articles.

Comment: So from this i came to know that both are having different meanings. Thank you for this. I was pretty confused with the first link since it is not explaining further..

Answer (score 0):

`Accessibilty` means that a `Java EE` application can be accessible around the world with the help of web. it's not wise to create a `Java SE` application having similar accessibility.

it's not a technical feature.